# Why is there no warning for missing initializer when using std::make_unique?

Tags: c++

In the code bellow the definition `S s2(2);` causes a compiler warning

```
warning: missing initializer for member 'S::s' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]
```

when compiled using `gcc-13.2` with the following options:

```
-std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra
```

However, when creating a `std::unique_ptr<S>` and passing it a single integer, the compiler does not warn:

```
auto s3 = std::make_unique<S>(3);
```

At the same time if a custom `make_unique` function is used

```
template<class T, class... Args>
auto make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

the compiler does warn: `warning: missing initializer for member 'S::s' [-Wmissing-field-initializers]`

Clang only complains regarding `S s4{2};`.

---

**Question:** how come the GCC does not warn of missing initializer when using `std::make_unique`, while in case of the custom version of `make_unique` it does detect the missing initializer and warn about it?

---

The code (https://godbolt.org/z/EP6xKsf1r):

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct S
{
    int n;
    std::string s;
};

template<class T, class... Args>
auto make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); //gcc complains
}

int main()
{
    S s1;
    S s2(2); // gcc complains
    auto s3 = std::make_unique<S>(3); // neither complain

    S s4{2}; // both complain
    auto s5 = make_unique<S>(3);
}
```

Comment: Can't imagine why any of them should complain, since `std::string` is default-constructible, it doesn't need an initializer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the veracity of this warning (since `s` has well-defined value when default initialized), the contents of system headers (among which standard library headers are included) are exempt from (most? some?) warnings. If you move your version to a header, and supply its directory path with `-isystem`, then the warning doesn't appear. [Here's a version of it on Compiler Explorer (it compares `-isystem` to `-I`)](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:tree,i:(cmakeArgs:%27-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE%3DDebug%27,compilerLanguageId:c%2B%2B,customOutputFilename:%27%27,files:!((editorId:1,fileId:2,filename:example.cpp,g:%27%27,isIncluded:%270%27,isMainSource:%270%27,isOpen:%270%27,langId:%27%27),(editorId:2,fileId:3,filename:header.h,g:%27%27,isIncluded:%270%27,isMainSource:%271%27,isOpen:%270%27,langId:%27%27)),isCMakeProject:%271%27,j:1,newFileId:4),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Tree+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:example.cpp,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:7,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:7,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:7,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:7,startLineNumber:15),source:%27%23include+%3Cmemory%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0A%23include+%3Cheader.h%3E%0A%0Astruct+S%0A%7B%0A++++int+n%3B%0A++++std::string+s%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++S+s1%3B%0A++++//S+s2(2)%3B+//+gcc+complains%0A++++auto+s3+%3D+std::make_unique%3CS%3E(3)%3B+//+neither+complain%0A%0A++++//S+s4%7B2%7D%3B+//+both+complain%0A++++auto+s5+%3D+make_unique%3CS%3E(3)%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:example.cpp,t:%270%27),(h:codeEditor,i:(filename:header.h,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27template%3Cclass+T,+class...+Args%3E%0Aauto+make_unique(Args%26%26...+args)%0A%7B%0A++++return+std::unique_ptr%3CT%3E(new+T(std::forward%3CArgs%3E(args)...))%3B+//gcc+complains%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:header.h,t:%270%27),(h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g132,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O2+-Wall+-Wpedantic+-Wextra+-isystem.%27,overrides:!(),runtimeTools:!(),stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(C%2B%2B,+Tree+%231)%27,t:%270%27),(h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:g132,compilerName:%27%27,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20+-O2+-Wall+-Wpedantic+-Wextra+-I.%27,overrides:!(),runtimeTools:!(),stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+13.2+(C%2B%2B,+Tree+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:2,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Basically:

##### header.h

```
template<class T, class... Args>
auto make_unique(Args&&... args)
{
    return std::unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)); //gcc complains
}
```

##### example.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <header.h>

struct S
{
    int n;
    std::string s;
};


int main()
{
    S s1;
    //S s2(2); // gcc complains
    auto s3 = std::make_unique<S>(3); // neither complain

    //S s4{2}; // both complain
    auto s5 = make_unique<S>(3);
}
```

Compiled with:

```
-std=c++20 -O2 -Wall -Wpedantic -Wextra -isystem.
```

And the error is nowhere to be seen. But it does appear if we use `-I.` instead of `-isystem.`, and take away the header's special privilege.